# List of all permutations

Tags: j

Verbs C. A. is related to permutations. 
And they have very complicated documentation. 
I want just get all possible permutations (n!) 
For example for elements 1 2 3

```
1 2 3
1 3 2 
2 1 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
3 2 1
```

Comment: Something simpler than this: (i.@!@#A.])'123'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left argument of `A.` is a *list* of permutation indeces.

Right argument of `A.` is the list to be permuted.

The initial (unpermuted) list has index 0 and it goes on from there lexicographically [*].

Egs:

```
(0) A. 'a';'b';'c'
┌─┬─┬─┐
│a│b│c│
└─┴─┴─┘

 (1 0) A. 1 2 3
1 3 2
1 2 3

(0 1 2) A. 5 1 2
5 1 2
5 2 1
1 5 2
```

To get *all* permutations of a list, you request all `(! #y)` (factorial of number of elements of list `y` to be permuted) of them, by requesting all indeces `0 ... (n-1)`: `i. (! # y)`:

```
(i.!#y) A. y
```

**[*]:** Lexicographically by the implied list `i. # y`. That is, `A.` always permutes the simple list `0 ... n` and then applies this permutation to your initial list:  `permutation { initial_list`.